# Dask division issue after groupby

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I am working on a project where I need to group by several columns depending on the task and I have unknown division issues with dask because of this.

Here is a sample of the problem

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd 
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.random.randint(1, 100, 100000), "col2": np.random.randint(101, 200, 100000), "col3": np.random.uniform(0, 4, 100000)})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)

ddf = ddf.set_index("col1")

ddf["col2_sum"] = ddf.groupby("col1")["col3"].transform("sum", meta=('x', 'float64')) # works
print(ddf.compute())
```

This works because I am grouping by an indexed column. However,

```py
ddf["col2_sum2"] = ddf.groupby("col2")["col3"].transform("sum", meta=('x', 'float64'))
```

This doesn't work because of  `` ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index. ``

I have tried to solve this this way

```py
ddf_new = ddf[["col2", "col3"]].set_index("col2")

ddf_new["col2_sum2"] = ddf_new.groupby("col2")["col3"].transform("sum", meta=('x', 'float64'))

ddf_new = ddf_new.drop(columns=["col3"])

ddf = ddf.merge(ddf_new, on=["col2"], how="outer") # works but expensive round trip

print(ddf.compute())
```

But this is very expensive [dask merges](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-groupby.html). Is there a better way of solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution you created seems reasonable, I would make one improvement (if this is feasible with actual data): if `ddf_new` is computed, then it becomes a pandas df, so the merge of `ddf` and `ddf_new` becomes a lot faster as there is less data to shuffle around.

Update: also to avoid sending the pandas df from workers to client and back, you could do a `ddf_new = client.compute(ddf_new)` and pass around just the future (reference to the computed pandas df).

Comment: I almost never call compute except when I filter down to a column. The data is too large.